# Same column query for different conditions

Tags: sql, multiple-conditions

I have a table like below, please help me building it.

Example:

```
column 1    column 2
111111      100
111111      101
111111      102
222222      101
222222      102
333333      100
```

So I am looking for column1 which has only 100 but not 101 or 102 for the same column.

From my above example, `333333  100` is exactly I am looking for, which has 100 but not 101 and 102.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Provide SQL sample you have so far.

Comment: I am building this in DB2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `group by` and `having` if you want the `column1` value:

```
select column1
from t
group by column1
having sum(case when column2 = 100 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when column2 in (101, 102) then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

If these are the only three values you care about, you can simplify this to:

```
select column1
from t
where column2 in (100, 101, 102)
group by column1
having max(column2) = 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `not exists` operator

```
SELECT *
FROM table t1
WHERE column2 = 100
AND NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT * FROM table t2
  WHERE t1.column1 = t2.column1
    AND t2.column2 in (101, 102)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might be trying to do a pivot query:

https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/pivot.php